# "500 - Internal server error" - Finding out more info?

Tags: php, windows-server-2008

I'm getting a hell of a lot of 500 internal server errors on our web application right now. I've been off three weeks and just came back and genuinely have no idea what has caused it.

The problem I've got is that this error message is so vague, I have no idea what exactly is going on!

On our old server it used to display proper PHP messages, on this one (IIS on Server 2008) it just says that and nothing else.

Is there anyway to find out what's going on? I can't even find the error logs (just some W3C log that logs all requests) or anything like that!

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to say without any more information.  Could be a number of things.

Comment: I guess you've already check this, but ask never harmed anyone : Have you checked errors logs on both PHP and IIS side ?

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311766 Not specifically your version, but it may help.